# Need to find files modified between 15 and 5 minutes ago

Tags: bash, scripting, find

I'm trying to find all files in a given folder that were modified withing a certain time frame, say between 5 and 15 minutes ago.

Currently I can find anything modified say up to 15 minutes ago by using find -cmin

```
#!/bin/bash

minutes="15"

FILETYPES=`find . *PATTERN*.txt* -maxdepth 0 -type f -cmin -$minutes`
```

How do I give it a time frame?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this :

```
find . -name '*pattern.txt' -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -mmin -15 -a -mmin +5 \)
```

#### Notes

- the parenthesis are not mandatory here with **and** : `-a`, but it's necessary for case with **or**: `-o`
- always use single quotes around the pattern to prevent shell expansion of the wildcard
- to give a pattern, use `-name` or `-iname`
- for the date/hour, `-mmin` is the way to go for minutes and `-mtime` for days.

Comment: Hi Would you mind giving me a couple clarifications: Why change -maxdepth to 1? What do you mean prevent shell expansion of the windcard? I'm looking for a pattern in the file name that can potentially be at any position This does not seem to return what does the -mmin +5 do?

Comment: `-maxdepth 1` is the minimum to treat only the current dir or one specified. `-mmin +5` search files older than 5 minutes and -15 search for files less than 15 minutes. For shell expansion, a search on google will helps ;)

Comment: Quick update on this: using maxdepth 0 I get the desired results, particularly when I then use wc -l, to get both the file name and line count (with awk). When using -maxdepth 1, the filename returned is "/filename" instead of "filename". Also using quotes around *pattern searches for files with a * in the name (and thus returns nothing). Anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: One more Question, when using this it prints the full path + the file name is it possible to only grab the filename instead?

Comment: Yes, use `-printf '%f\n'`

Answer (score 2):

Using `find`, you can add additional conditions to create the range. Each condition is implied as "and" unless `-o` is used. You also want `-mmin` instead of `-cmin` for modified time (but they are often the same).

```
find . '*PATTERN*.txt*' -maxdepth 0 -type f -mmin -15 -mmin +5
```